# Responsive Web Site

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, static, cell

I have a static web site with 100+ pages. It needs to be mobile responsive. I plan to outsource this work, as I have only basic HTML skills. If the freelance programmer writes the code for one page, can I implement the code myself for the other pages? All the pages have the same width and use a common template.

Please also inform the key questions I have to ask the programmer to decide to award the project.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Let me put it that way: If you have to ask this question, the answer is most likely "No, you can't." The key questions you should ask are "Do you have any experience with responsive CSS frameworks?" Furthermore, this question is pretty off-topic, since SO is aimed at solving problems with code, not with coders. ;)

Comment: Its better if you let the programmer do the job. He should be aware of responsive css frameworks.

Comment: 100 + pages sounds a lot of work and even an experienced web designer will tell you it will be cheaper for you in the long run if you went a did a course in Content Management Frameworks like Joomla, drupal etc or even wordpress

Answer (score 1):

You can reuse his code if you know how to do it properly. Probably that job requres knowledge of professional so if you are newbie in html site with 100+ pages would be very wrong step for you.

And only, if changes/differences to those pages are really small and minimalistic.

Also, keep in mind that something can look good to you, but a professional will se if that code is optimised for many browsers, Google search, PC and mobile version, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You could reuse it if u know the changes he made. 
Otherwise, to make it mobile responsive to some extent, you could add this meta tag on the head section on each page.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: Please describe more in answer. It will be helpful for questioner to have more comprehension of answer.